# Crystal Report subreport blank field only deploy , in designer preview printer field exists

Tags: crystal-reports, field, subreport

Crystal report version 2020

In Crystal Report Designer have "subreport" and have update Store     Procedure in Field Explorer see new field, add new field in    "subreport" in print preview I see the fields
but after deploy report and performed test see blank new field.
If run SP in "sql" management studio , get the correct query  result.

> ```
> In Crystal Report Designer i performed the following steps:
> Database > Connect/Disconnect 
> Database > Verify Database
> Field Explorer > Expert Database remove add SP with << >>
> Field Explorer > Preview Printer > Browser Field see value field
> ```

what could be the solution, possible that i have to restart server???!!!!!

version Crystal Report 2020 (13.0)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One explanation is that you originally inserted the subreport into the main report from an existing rpt file.

Right-click the subreport object and select 'Format Subreport'
Go to the 'Subreport' tab and make sure the option to 'Re-import When Opening' is turned off.

Otherwise, the original external .rpt would override your changes to the subreport.
[image]